# Character Count in C

Tags: c, getchar

The folllowing C Program is  to calculate the character Count .

```
#include <stdio.h >
int main()
{
   int nc = 0;
   while (getchar() != EOF)
   {
      ++nc;
      printf("%d\n", nc); 
   }
    return 0;
}
```

When I Enter a character , for example 'y'  in the terminal , The output returns as follows

```
1
2
```

How does this calculation happens and why 2 is in the output?

Comment: Try entering a longer string. My guess is that you will always see ONE EXTRA (i.e. if you enter ABCD, you will get 1 2 3 4 5).

Comment: Because you entered two characters - newline perhaps

Comment: I bet you didn't just push `y` but you pushed another character after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you didn't know but when you press enter you just insert a newline character or `'\n'`. If you want to get the correct result ignore the newline character or just decrease the nc by one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int nc = 0;
  while (getchar() != EOF)
  {
    ++nc;
    printf("Character count is:%d\n", nc - 1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Even better code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int nc = 0;
  for(;;)
  {
    do
      ++nc;
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("Character count is:%d\n", nc - 1);
    nc = 0;
  }
}
```

The updated code will reset your counter back to 0.

Comment: Why `... nc = 1;`?

Comment: Yeah,you're right I messed up my code with something else.Thanks! I'll fix it.

Comment: ```++nc;``` . Correct the syntax problem. :)

Comment: Sorry,was writing from a phone :)

Comment: The first code fragment will just print `0 1`, no special handling of `'\n'`. The second fragment will run an endless loop because you never test for `EOF`.

Comment: Yes I know,I didn't want to end the loop in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You ENTERed "a character". A `y` and a new line character. That's 2.

Answer (score 1):

Because you entered two character. One is `y` and another one is `\n`(newline) character.

Hence you get the output 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count only the visible bytes, you can use the `isprint` function, which returns whether a byte is printable or the space character. It goes like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int nc = 0;
  int ch;

  while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if (isprint(ch) && ch != ' ')
      ++nc;
    printf("Character count after reading '%c' is %d.\n",ch, nc);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that since in C, a `char` is not a Unicode character but often just a byte, this program counts some characters as 2 or more bytes, for example emojis, Cyrillic letters, Chinese ideographs.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit enter it's considered a character